# change lines are very slow in Rstudio on Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

In the past few days, I am experiencing this weird problem which I never had before. When I want to change lines (by hitting return button) in Rstudio, it is almost frozen for a few seconds (have the spinning loading sign on Mac). It's really annoying now, as it happens almost every time I change lines. I tried to restart my computer, closed all other applications, and even updated Rstudio, but problem doesn't go away. I am on Rstudio version 0.99.486, and OS X version 10.9.5. Does anyone have this problem before, what's the matter? thanks!

Comment: You don't want to hear this, but you really should update your Mac OS. You're well behind. For the record, I have been using RStudio all morning with nary a delay. `R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)` and RStudio Version 0.99.467

Comment: clear your console history (ctrl-l when focused on the console). RStudio is a giant webkit app with a bunch of iframes that do not do well then there are many lines or long/many long lines (console or otherwise)